# Tag badge not awarded, waiting for a week

Tags: support, tag-badges

I have [20 answers in object tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:343721+[object]) with score of more than 100, however I didn't obtain the bronze tag badge, although it has been a week since I meet the criteria.

I know the awarding script runs [0300 UTC sometimes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226681/tag-scores-are-not-updated-and-the-issue-is-getting-worse), but the delay is longer now.

Or do I miss something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The query you should be using is this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A343721+[object]+is%3Aanswer+wiki%3A0

You have 20 posts in [object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object) total:

- 2 are questions.
- 18 are answers, one of which is a wiki so it doesn't count.

So as of right now, you only have 17. Just 3 more and you'll have the badge.

Comment: Also questions that received the tag only through retagging are not counted.

Comment: @false Is that new? I remember in the past, retagging still counted.

Comment: @false There is no such rule.